# Are the IDictionary members implemented in ConcurrentDictionary thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When calling DoStuffToDictionary(dictionaryTwo), is it safe to assume the operations within the method body including indexers, and LINQ extension methods will also be thread safe?

To phrase this question differently, could a cross thread exception or deadlock arise?

```
var dictionaryOne = new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>();
var dictionaryTwo = new Dictionary<int,int>();

DoStuffToDictionary(dictionaryOne);
DoStuffToDictionary(dictionaryTwo);

void DoStuffToDictionary(IDictionary<int,int> items) {
   // Manipulate dictionary    

   if (items[0] == -1) {
     items[0] = 0; // Dumb example, but are indexers like this OK?
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `thread-safe`. You won't be able to call methods such as `GetOrAdd()` from the `IDictionary<>` interface.

Comment: I understand that :-), I'm talking about the thread safety offered by the dictionary itself.

Comment: To elaborate from your code sample, both calls to `items[0]` will indeed be thread-safe, but there's no guarantee that another thread won't run between the two calls and modify `items[0]` (again, in a perfectly thread-safe manner) behind your back. If this behavior is not acceptable, you'll have to use `GetOrAdd()`, so you won't be able to rely on `IDictionary<>`.

Comment: your question it too general... plase be more specific...

Comment: Yes that's true, but is the value returned via the indexer always the latest value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several problems with this code:

1. **`IDictionary` interface can be implemented by any type of a dictionary**
   Your example is certainly not thread safe, since you are working on an `IDictionary<int,int>` interface, which doesn't guarantee any thread safety. Even your code passes both a `Dictionary` and a `ConcurrentDictionary` to the method.
2. **Transactions need to be atomic to make them thread-safe**
   Even if the dictionary implementation was guaranteed to be thread safe, your code wouldn't be because you are not locking the access to your dictionary **between two calls**:

   ```
   if (items[0] == -1) {
       // <-- another thread can access items in this moment
       items[0] = 0;
   }
   ```
3. **Returning a LINQ query is never thread-safe**
   If you are using LINQ to return `IEnumerable` or `IQueriable` from your method, then locks have little effect, unless you use the `ToList()` method to evaluate the expression immediatelly and cache results. This is due to the fact that a LINQ only "prepares" the query for execution. If you are returning an `IEnumerable` from a method, actual dictionary will be accessed **after** your method ends (and therefore, outside the lock).

The biggest problem with this code lies in the fact that you are **passing the `IDictionary` instance around**, which means that other parts of your code can access it directly, and must lock on the same lock object instance very carefully. This is painful, error-prone to implement correctly, easy to break by accident, and hard to detect (race conditions may show symptoms on rare occasions).

You can do several things to improve the code:

1. **Don't pass the `IDictionary` around, but instead your own interface (preferred)**
   Make the dictionary a private member of a class which implements some custom interface, abstract all operations, and use a lock to ensure thread safety (or use a `ConcurrentDictionary` under the hood). This way you are sure that all calls are being locked using the same lock instance.
2. **Don't use the interface, but rather always pass the `ConcurrentDictionary`**
   This will be thread safe as long as you use specific **atomic** methods which a `ConcurrentDictionary` provides (`GetOrAdd`, `AddOrUpdate`, etc.). Using simple access methods like you did in your example won't be thread safe, which means you still need to be careful with it. Additional downside is that you won't be able to abstract the functionality if you ever need to (it will be impossible to wrap/proxy the dictionary, and you won't be able to use other dictionary implementations).
3. **Pass the `IDictionary` around, and lock on the dictionary itself (not recommended at all).**
   This is an ugly hack, which is unfortunately used more often than it should be. It means you need to do this in **every** part of your app which accesses this dictionary, taking additional care to lock multiple operations along the way.

Comment: items[0] = 0; What about data corruption? Will items[n] always be the latest value?

Comment: @VinceP: if the dictionary is concurrent itself, or you lock the entire operation, `items[0]=0;` will assign the value for this key, without corruption. But if you don't lock around the `if` clause, multiple threads can pass inside the body of the `if` clause, and then update the value for the same key, one by one. If your intention is to allow this key to be written **only once** (i.e. if value is -1, change it, but if it's not, don't change it anymore), then you need to add a `lock` statement around the whole transaction.

Comment: @VinceP: so, yes, if dictionary is concurrent (if at least individual operations are locked), you will be able to read the "last value" of `items[n]` without corruption. But you should be aware that this is of little value, if you continue to pass the dictionary around without locking transactions. You may get away with some simple scenarios, but it's a race condition waiting to happen. The best thing to do would be to add a new question to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), with some details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

the lines (together)

```
   if (items[0] == -1) {
     items[0] = 0; // Dumb example, but are indexers like this OK?
```

are NOT thread-safe... with a ConcurrentDictionary this

```
    ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> D = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
    D.TryUpdate(0, 0, -1); // this is threadsade regarding a ConcurrentDictionary
```

would be threadsafe with the result you want to achieve with the above lines.

Answer (score 1):

1) For the `Dictionary` LINQ extension methods are not a thread safe because the class itself is not a thread safe, but for the `ConcurrentDictionary` it is a thread safe and so calling the `LINQ` extensions functions for it is thread safe .

**Edit:**

2) `Is it safe to assume the operations within the method body including indexers` I don't know what you are mean by `including indexers` but if you are referring to that the dictionaries is not empty. then for the `Dictionary` you should not consider that it contains items.. however for the `ConcurrentDictionary` you can use methods like: `AddOrUpdate();, GetOrAdd();, TryAdd();, TryGetValue();`